# Prometheus. Can I define a variable at graph level?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I know I can create a variable at dashboard level, but is it possible to create a variable at graph level, this is a variable that makes sense for a specific graph inside the dashboard but does not apply to all the other graphs.

Comment: Are you referring to Grafana template variables by any chance?

Comment: yes, but template variables are defined at dashboard level, I was asking for something more related to a specific graph. I can use dashboards variables.

Comment: This is more of a Grafana type question as far as I can tell. You can't create a variable at the graph level as you have put it.